# Unable to display error message in play1.2.4 framework html

Tags: html, validation, error-handling, playframework-1.x

I am currently using play framework. Here I need to display error message corresponding to a text box.

Below is the structure of the code I have been using --

```
<div class="row-fluid widgetRow span6 ${errors.forKey('orgName') ? 'error' : ''}">
    <div class="span5 dataLabel"><label class="control-label noMargin " for="orgName">
        Org Name</label><span class="required" title="required"> *</span></label></div>
    <div class="span7 controls"><input id="orgName" class="" name="orgName" type="text"/></div>
</div>
```

Now the issue that I am facing is that, infact in a conceptual manner too, is that after I am firing an ajax save on the page, there is some play validation error(validation.required(...)) checks done in the backend, but the conditional class is never getting change. In fact as per my concept I think the condition of the class must be checked during the load of the page.

I hope this makes sense.
Please help me with this, whether there is somewhere I am mistaken

Comment: Tag your question with used version of Play

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally either use [`#{ifError 'orgName'}error#{/ifError}`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/tags#iferror) or [`#{errorClass 'orgName'/}`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/tags#errorClass) (and edit the CSS to include `.hasError`).

Aside from that, are you sure you are using the right key? You could check what errors are actually there by adding this to your template to output all errors:

```html
#{ifErrors}
    <p>Error(s) found!</p>
    <ul>
        #{errors}
            <li>[${error_index}] ${error.key}: ${error}</li>
        #{/errors}
    </ul>
#{/ifErrors}
```